# Passing pyqt opengl context to C++ for rendering

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, pyqt, rendering

I am working on a physics simulation tool. Right now it is just a console application, no GUI, etc, but I would like to add it at some point. The application has a very simple renderer so that I can see the results of a simulation.

I have used PyQt in the past and I liked it for GUI developing, so I am wondering if it is possible to create a GUI in PyQt, and use the OpenGL contexts from the QGLWidgets in my C++ renderer. Now I'm using SDL for rendering and event handling, so the idea would be to use the OpenGL context generated in PyQt instead.

Does anyone know if it is possible? I have been looking for a possible solution but I haven't found any clear answer or example doing it. If it is not possible, do you know of any other possibility for developing a GUI in python and using a C++ renderer?

Comment: Is this specifically about using QGLWidget's OpenGL context or also about running your C++ code from python?

Comment: I was planning on using Boost.Python or SWIG to run python from C++, but I haven't really experimented with it yet. However, the renderer is the piece of code that I have no clue about how to glue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use SWIG (swig.org) to wrap your C++ renderer library into a python module, which can then import into your pyqt app. This assumes your C++ lib has the appropriate functions that you must call from the class you derive from QGLWidget (initializeGL, resizeGL, paintGL), but it should be pretty straightforward otherwise.

There is no reason that Boost.Python wouldn't work same way as SWIG. The specifics don't matter much; ultimately your python script is calling C++ functions and methods so there has to be code that converts python data to C++ data and back, if this is done properly then you can focus on your GUI.

Comment: Ok, I understand this approach. Has anyone tried it before? I have never used SWIG yet, but it is definitely one of the options I was considering. However, since I am planning on using only python, and I am currently using Boost for other tasks I was slightly biased towards using Boost.Python. Would a similar approach work in that case?

Comment: sure; extended my answer